# Pandas dataframe add values in a loop

Tags: pandas

I am trying to append dynamically to a dataframe a single value that i am generating in a loop.

```
global results_df
results_df=pd.DataFrame()

avg =109

std_dev = 12

# Loop through many simulations
for i in range(1000):    
    # Choose random inputs 
    rev_sim = np.random.normal(avg, std_dev, 1).round(0)#Rounding to 0 decimals

    # Build the dataframe based on the inputs
    df_res = pd.DataFrame(data={'REV_SIM': rev_sim})
    results_df.append(df_res)
```

But my results_df is empty.

Comment: Could you please add your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not assign it back

```
for i in range(1000):    
    # Choose random inputs 
    rev_sim = np.random.normal(avg, std_dev, 1).round(0)#Rounding to 0 decimals

    # Build the dataframe based on the inputs
    df_res = pd.DataFrame(data={'REV_SIM': rev_sim})
    results_df=results_df.append(df_res)# assign it back
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

avg = 109
std_dev = 12

N  = 1000
rev_sim = np.random.normal(avg, std_dev, N).round(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'REV_SIM':rev_sim})
```

**UPDATE:**

Timing

Wen-Ben's solution

```
%%timeit -n10
global results_df
results_df=pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(1000):    
    # Choose random inputs 
    rev_sim = np.random.normal(avg, std_dev, 1).round(0)#Rounding to 0 decimals

    # Build the dataframe based on the inputs
    df_res = pd.DataFrame(data={'REV_SIM': rev_sim})
    results_df=results_df.append(df_res)# assign it back 

1.08 s ± 36.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

My solution

```
%%timeit -n10
N  = 1000
rev_sim = np.random.normal(avg, std_dev, N).round(0)
result_df = pd.DataFrame({'REV_SIM':rev_sim})

748 µs ± 153 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

If you really need to generate entries via a loop it's better to define an array first and then append it to your `df`

```
%%timeit -n10
rev_sim = [np.random.normal(avg, std_dev, 1).round(0) for i in range(1000)]
result_df = pd.DataFrame({'REV_SIM':rev_sim})

6.55 ms ± 888 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

The last version is 8.64x slower than the one I proposed while the Wen-Ben's solution is ~1444x slower.

Pandas could get really slow with loops.